# need to get xml data from soap service

Tags: xml, soap

I need to get an xml from my supplier containing data that will be proccesed in Excel.
Unfortunatly i have no experience in writing a php script to get that data.

My question is is there any other way to get this data? some specialized software witch will connect to my suppllier wsdl address and fetch that data?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I use apache axis2 wsdl2java to autogenerate client code for java. Does yours have to be done in PHP?

Comment: it is not my server so i really dont know in what the server is done, i tried to write a php code to get the data, but i'm not verry good with code so i'm way over my head!

Comment: The link I just provided should hopefully do it. You then just have to interact with the PHP as opposed to interacting with a WSDL, making it much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing web services I've always used SoapUI - http://www.soapui.org/

It's a pretty neat tool and has a lot of features. If you use the free version that should do what you need which is call the service and retrieve the data in an XML format

Comment: thanks for the tip, i'll try it right now and get back with feedback

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but this looks promising:

http://www.urdalen.no/wsdl2php/index.php

This will generate client code from the WSDL provided, and then you just have to write the code to get what you need from the generated PHP code.